# Can I pass my worlds on Minecraft Pocket Edition, on a iPad2, to a Minecraft edition on a Mac?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, ios, macos

I have an iPad2, with a Pocket Edition on it, but with an old iOs, and I can't play normally on it, because its a really old iPad, the question is, can I pass my worlds to an iMac Minecraft edition ?

Comment: You can use a world conversion program, just send the world folder from the *files* app to the Mac and use a conversion app to change it.